# Existence of different Super Mario World versions

Tags: super-mario-world

Years ago, I had an argument with a friend about the colors of the Yoshis in Super Mario World. I claimed them to be green, red, yellow, and blue; my friend argued that the colors were green, red, yellow, and purple. (His argument, which is admittedly challenging to refute, is, "Look at it.") We've had this argument continually for over a decade.

Like everyone else with a pulse, I've been playing around with [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com). I decided to see how it would do in settling this dispute. Here was its response:

[image: ChatGPT attempt at settling Yoshi debate]

My immediate response, based on my experience, was that nearly none of this is true. But, I hesitated because of the claim that there are different versions. After some searching, I still have no evidence that this is true, but I have seen some strange things that still leave me with a bit of doubt, such as [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-do-the-different-colored-yoshis-do-in-Super-Mario-World) in which someone again asserts there to be six Yoshis (albeit a different six than what ChatGPT told me).

My question is: **Is there any truth to either the claim of six Yoshis or of some alternate versions?** Certainly, there are localized versions in different languages, but I'm asking if there's a more profound version difference of some sort that I have missed.

I imagine this answer comes from a conflation of SMW with some entirely different game (SMW2: Yoshi's Island, perhaps? Or Yoshi's Story?) but I can't seem to find a perfect match to support that assertion. I think this is an important example about the inherent limitations of AI language models, but I'd like to be just a bit more confident that I have the facts right before using that example.

Comment: So you are basically asking: how many Yoshis are there? I appreciate the effort you put into this, but I believe a lot of this post doesn't really add anything to it.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear; I'm asking if there exist other versions of Super Mario World besides the one I'm familiar with, which has 4 Yoshis.

Comment: You can [edit] your post to clarify things. You might want to start with the title, since it doesn't mention Yoshis, yet you seem to focus on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Fandom](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/Yoshi_(species)):

> There [are] eleven known colors. Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Light Blue, Blue, Pink, Purple, White, Black and Brown.
>
> [image]
> <sup>The Yoshi Clan, with every colour except Brown Yoshi.</sup>

- [Green](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/Yoshi), [Red](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/Red_Yoshi), [Yellow](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/Yellow_Yoshi), and [Blue](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/Blue_Yoshi) Yoshi appear in *Super Mario World* (making you the winner of your argument :).
- [Light Blue](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/Light_Blue_Yoshi), [Pink](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/Pink_Yoshi), [Purple](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/Purple_Yoshi), and [Brown](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/Brown_Yoshi) Yoshi appear in *Super Mario World 2*.
- [Black](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Yoshi) and [White](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/White_Yoshi) Yoshi first appeared in *Yoshi's Story*.
- [Orange](https://yoshi.fandom.com/wiki/Orange_Yoshi) Yoshi's first appearance is in *Game & Watch Gallery 3*.
- There is a more extensive overview on [MarioWiki.com](https://www.mariowiki.com/Yoshi_(species)).
  This page adds [a Magenta and a Gold variation](https://www.mariowiki.com/Yoshi_(species)#Color_variations), but their viability/existence depends slightly on your interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think this settles it -- ChatGPT is making things up or conflating them with something else.